# Check if two vector equations of parametric surfaces are equivalent

Tags: multivariable-calculus, parametric

Give the vector equation of the plane through these lines:

$\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}\,\,\,$ and $\,\,\,\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\0\\3\end{pmatrix}+\mu\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

My answer is: $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\\2\end{pmatrix}+\mu\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\-3\\1\end{pmatrix}$. The solutions manual suggests the following equation, which is the equation of a straight line (probably a typo): $\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}4\\1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\lambda\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}+\mu\cdot\begin{pmatrix}0\\2\\1\end{pmatrix}$

Is my solution the right solution? Could someone provide a general way to check?

Comment: Your answer is right.

Answer (score 1):

You have two planes that go through the same point (4,1,1). Now all you need is having them parallel. You can check this by forming the cross product of the defining vectors, i.e. (0,-1,2) and (0,-3-1) for the first plane, that will give you a normal to the plane. Do the same for the second plane; if your normal vectors are parallel, so are the planes and hence identical in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Since the first equation describes a plane whereas the second one describes a straight line the equations aren't equivalent.

Comment: I already thought so....

Comment: Michael's got the right of it, hence why I've withdrawn my answer. Note though that the line does lie in the plane given in your answer; that suggests to me that there's a typo in their answer, and the second vector should've been different. @user3761304

Comment: How can we tell without knowing the exercise?

Comment: Would it be ok to add the original exercise?

Comment: Assuming that the problem above is an accurate transcription, the two are indeed inequivalent. Though without the exercise itself, we're having to speculate a bit... @user3761304

Comment: I completely edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

But the really simple way is to pick three arbitrary points (not on the same line) from the first plane and check if they all lie in the second one.